# Can we export/import Users, Groups, Publication Targets and Target Types using Content Porter

Tags: 2013, content-porter-2013

Can we export/import Users, Groups, Publication Targets and Target Types using Content Porter ? I believe yes but Just curious !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope Vikas, Content porter tool not provides option to choose the staff that are comes under the Administrative part (except User group/ Permission / Associated Workflow) for export/import. Please check the below options if you want to export/import the security and workflow

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more.
As far as I know if I have Admin privilege over CMS then I do see Administrator section and Groups that can be exported.
I have this information that Users and Permissions can not be imported (Curiosity is why?)

Comment: Permission and Security you can export/import but other options like Publishing Target, Target Type these things are not accessible from this Tool.

Comment: Ok..cool. I guess this is the case.
But is this can be achieved using core service scripts?

Comment: I am not sure, But you can try with Import/Export API.

Answer (score 6):

You can export Group but not their permission settings (on organizational items). [SDL Docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B562B17F-6112-43CD-AE4B-84F370B4C4F8) lists the following non-exportable items:

- Font definitions
- Protocol Schemas in publishing
- Schemas in publishing (I'm not sure what this means, actually)
- **Target types** in publishing
- **Publication Targets** in publishing
- Page and Component publishing status
- **Users**
- **Security settings for Users and Groups**
- **Permissions** for Publications, Folders, and Structure Groups
- Checked-in and checked-out status for Components, Template Building Blocks, Component Templates, Page Templates, Pages, and Schemas
- History list for Components, Template Building Blocks, Component
  Templates, Page Templates, and Pages
- Approval Status of individual
  items

SDL Web 8's Topology Manager addresses some of these by moving publication target-specific information out of the Content Manager (and Content Delivery) and into a environment-specific Topology.

Some of the other restrictions come from the fact users might be different and that you might have different authorization requirements between environments.

Answer (score 1):

The DTAP-It solution allows you to export/import Groups. the source code can be adapted to do Users and Publish Targets/Target Types.

https://community.sdl.com/developers/developers_archive/sdl_innovate_2015_spring_hackathon/w/teams/681.the-tappers

Answer (score 0):

The "Publishing Management" Items can't be ported using the client.
I can only export `User Groups`, `Workflow Approval Status` and `Multimedia Types` from Administration.

I am not sure about using the Import/Export API.

Comment: True. But I need to look into this by giving only publication Management permission to my team mates, We ll get back.